# extrema of step function.

Tags: calculus

Asking this because I am confused about definition of maximum and minimum of a function.

for example, as the title lists, $f\left(x\right) =  \lfloor x \rfloor$ from [4.1,4.9] and from [4.9 to 5.1]

Where is the relative, and/or absolute maximum? Also, wlog the min?

My book define the max($x_*$) as $f\left(x_*\right) \geq f\left(x\right)\, \forall \, x \in I$, where $I$ is the interval. and WLOG min $f\left(x_*\right) \leq f\left(x\right)\, \forall \, x \in I$.

Thus for a straight line, $x_*$ could be both a max or min value for all $x$ in the interval.  Just seems strange.

Comment: I'm not sure why things have to be 'without loss of generality' here. At any rate, if your function is constant then it's absolutely maximal and minimal everywhere, yes. Usually functions aren't constant, though.

Comment: @IanColey, just wondering, because of a problem  that was on the home work, had part of the graph that look like a straight line, and I got the question wrong, because I labeled the straight line section as both relative min/man.  the book labeled it as neither.

Comment: If it's a line of slope$\neq 0$, then your book is correct. For any small interval around $x$, there's always a point greater than $f(x)$ and a point smaller than $f(x)$. $f(x+\varepsilon)=f(x)+\varepsilon\cdot m$ and $f(x-\varepsilon)=f(x)-\varepsilon\cdot m$, where $m$ is the slope of the line. Hence there are neither maxima nor minima.

Comment: @IanColey, that is what confused me, because it look horizontal (thus slope = 0). So, I figured I maybe has some bad understanding.